# Is possible to fire a regular trigger throw API?

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, databinding

I would like to know if it is possible to fire an regular Trigger (the ones you define in the visual interface) using the API. I have done some test using this URL:

```
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction-experimental/v1/events
```

I was able to insert data in the associated Data Extension but I was not able to start my Customer Journey. After check my Trigger result I realized it was been rejected. The error displayed is `InteractionEventHandlerFailure`, so I supposed I am missing somthing or this option is only available using Custom Triggers.

**EDIT:**

This is the API call I did to fire the event:

```
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction-experimental/v1/events
Headers:
Authorization: Bearer [token]
Content-Type: application/json

Payload:
{
  "ContactKey": "xxxxxxxxx@domain.com",
  "EventDefinitionKey": "CONTACT-EVENT-fcf8bda2-0d34-1884-a45a-416a44c3efc9",
  "Data": {
    "FirstName": "nish",
    "LastName": "nish",
    "Email": "xxxxxxxxx@domain.com" 
  }
}
```

I found in the status page calls this error:

```
ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Activities.AllowMultipleDecision.ContactKey: Error binding data bound member.
```

As you can see in my API call I have set the ContactKey and I have also verified that this contact key exists and it is properly bound at the Contact Builder. Note that the real ContactKey **was replaced by xxxxxxxxx@domain.com**.

Here is the full error log:

```
{  
   "took":513,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{  
      "total":24,
      "successful":24,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{  
      "total":5,
      "max_score":null,
      "hits":[  
         {  
            "_index":"trace_event_s7-2015-03-07",
            "_type":"event",
            "_id":"a8f51bcf-e8b7-41d4-8832-e8630b64726d",
            "_score":null,
            "_source":{  
               "id":"a8f51bcf-e8b7-41d4-8832-e8630b64726d",
               "mid":7204044,
               "eventId":"e17dd4f7-d3c1-4b71-8c06-bd29e31e6ab6",
               "definitionId":"670c6a3b-1d82-435e-9813-5b477b25cf64",
               "definitionName":"TLMK-TRIGGER-TEST",
               "eventName":"TLMK-DE-001-AUTO-TRIGGER",
               "contactKey":"xxxxxxxxx@domain.com",
               "transactionTime":1426161671226,
               "status":"Failed",
               "message":{  
                   "result":{  
                      "error":{  
                         "ClassName":"ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Engine.DataBoundException",
                         "Message":"ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Activities.AllowMultipleDecision.ContactKey: Error binding data bound member.",
                         "Data":null,
                         "InnerException":{  
                            "ClassName":"ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Binding.EvaluatedExpressionException",
                            "Message":"Error rendering required expression [{{Contact.Key}}] value [] to data type [System.String]",
                            "Data":null,
                            "InnerException":null,
                            "HelpURL":null,
                            "StackTraceString":"   at ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Binding.Evaluators.ExpressionEvaluator.Evaluate[T](String expression, WorkflowContext context, Activity activity, Boolean optional)\r\n   at ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Workflow.Activities.Binding.DataBound`1.DataBind(IExpressionEvaluator evaluator, WorkflowContext context, Activity activity, Boolean optional)\r\n   at ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Engine.EngineImpl.<>c__DisplayClasse.<BindData>b__d()",
                            "RemoteStackTraceString":null,
                            "RemoteStackIndex":0,
                            "ExceptionMethod":"8\nEvaluate\nExactTarget.InteractionStudio, Version=151.2.1.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c3ca85e74a7e49d9\nExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Binding.Evaluators.ExpressionEvaluator\nT Evaluate[T](System.String, ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Workflow.WorkflowContext, ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Workflow.Activities.Activity, Boolean)",
                            "HResult":-2146233088,
                            "Source":"ExactTarget.InteractionStudio",
                            "WatsonBuckets":null
                         },
                         "HelpURL":null,
                         "StackTraceString":"   at ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Engine.EngineImpl.<>c__DisplayClasse.<BindData>b__d()\r\n   at ExactTarget.Diagnostics.StatsCollection.RecordMetric(String[] names, Action action)\r\n   at ExactTarget.Diagnostics.Stats.Time(String tag, Action action)\r\n   at ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Engine.EngineImpl.Process(EngineInstanceInfo instanceInfo)",
                         "RemoteStackTraceString":null,
                         "RemoteStackIndex":0,
                         "ExceptionMethod":"8\n<BindData>b__d\nExactTarget.InteractionStudio, Version=151.2.1.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c3ca85e74a7e49d9\nExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Engine.EngineImpl+<>c__DisplayClasse\nVoid <BindData>b__d()",
                         "HResult":-2146233088,
                         "Source":"ExactTarget.InteractionStudio",
                         "WatsonBuckets":null
                      },
                      "status":"Fail"
                   },
                   "parameters":{  
                      "ContactKey":"NULL",
                      "DefinitionId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                      "ConditionOutcome":false
                   }
                },
               "properties":null,
               "activityName":"",
               "activityId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
               "activityType":"Other"
            },
            "sort":[  
               1426161671226
            ]
         },
         {  
            "_index":"trace_event_s7-2015-03-07",
            "_type":"event",
            "_id":"cdcc914f-30ae-420b-8b03-eaa7c79d6590",
            "_score":null,
            "_source":{  
               "id":"cdcc914f-30ae-420b-8b03-eaa7c79d6590",
               "mid":7204044,
               "eventId":"e17dd4f7-d3c1-4b71-8c06-bd29e31e6ab6",
               "definitionId":"670c6a3b-1d82-435e-9813-5b477b25cf64",
               "definitionName":"TLMK-TRIGGER-TEST",
               "eventName":"TLMK-DE-001-AUTO-TRIGGER",
               "contactKey":"xxxxxxxxx@domain.com",
               "transactionTime":1426161669775,
               "status":"InteractionEventHandled",
               "message":null,
               "properties":null
            },
            "sort":[  
               1426161669775
            ]
         },
         {  
            "_index":"trace_event_s7-2015-03-07",
            "_type":"event",
            "_id":"b86c88dc-32a3-42b7-a5f4-2dc8bb6c7b7c",
            "_score":null,
            "_source":{  
               "id":"b86c88dc-32a3-42b7-a5f4-2dc8bb6c7b7c",
               "mid":7204044,
               "eventId":"e17dd4f7-d3c1-4b71-8c06-bd29e31e6ab6",
               "definitionId":"670c6a3b-1d82-435e-9813-5b477b25cf64",
               "definitionName":"TLMK-TRIGGER-TEST",
               "eventName":"TLMK-DE-001-AUTO-TRIGGER",
               "contactKey":"xxxxxxxxx@domain.com",
               "transactionTime":1426161669744,
               "status":"ContactAttempted",
               "message":null,
               "properties":null
            },
            "sort":[  
               1426161669744
            ]
         },
         {  
            "_index":"trace_event_s7-2015-03-07",
            "_type":"event",
            "_id":"45a42e29-7903-44ae-86af-5625347a1f1f",
            "_score":null,
            "_source":{  
               "id":"45a42e29-7903-44ae-86af-5625347a1f1f",
               "mid":7204044,
               "eventId":"e17dd4f7-d3c1-4b71-8c06-bd29e31e6ab6",
               "definitionId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
               "definitionName":"",
               "eventName":"TLMK-DE-001-AUTO-TRIGGER",
               "contactKey":"xxxxxxxxx@domain.com",
               "transactionTime":1426161669713,
               "status":"EventQueuedForProcessing",
               "message":null,
               "properties":null
            },
            "sort":[  
               1426161669713
            ]
         },
         {  
            "_index":"trace_event_s7-2015-03-07",
            "_type":"event",
            "_id":"50640b72-e7cf-4551-8403-f65216aca924",
            "_score":null,
            "_source":{  
               "id":"50640b72-e7cf-4551-8403-f65216aca924",
               "mid":7204044,
               "eventId":"e17dd4f7-d3c1-4b71-8c06-bd29e31e6ab6",
               "definitionId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
               "definitionName":"",
               "eventName":"TLMK-DE-001-AUTO-TRIGGER",
               "contactKey":"xxxxxxxxx@domain.com",
               "transactionTime":1426161669666,
               "status":"EventQueuedForProcessing",
               "message":"Source = MsmqService",
               "properties":null
            },
            "sort":[  
               1426161669666
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error may be due to a variety of reasons; for instance, if your email is invalid or your data-binding isn't valid).  When viewing the status page (Admin/Contacts) open the Network tab in Dev Tools in Chrome and click on the traceevents route.  More detail is contained in the Response tab.  Copy the json and paste into a json pretty printer to format it.  There should be an error in there showing why it failed.

In a chrome extension like PostMan:

```
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction-experimental/v1/events
Headers:
Authorization: Bearer [token]
Content-Type: application/json

Payload:
{
"ContactKey":"[email]",
"EventDefinitionKey":"CONTACT-EVENT-[guid]",
"Data": {
    "EmailAddress":"[email]",
    "trigger_key":[trigger value],
  "other":"data"
    }
}
```

More custom activity information [here](https://github.com/sfmc-developer-advocates/custom-activity-deskapi-node).

**Update**: the error log indicates a databinding error:

```
"Message":"Error rendering required expression [{{Contact.Key}}] value [] to data type [System.String]",
```

Comment: I updated the question adding log details. I still can't find the problen. Any guess?

Comment: I updated my answer.  Can you post your config.json?  Also, what is your trigger look like?  What key/value combination(s) will trigger the interaction?

Comment: There is no such a config.json. This an regular trigger, not a custom one. I tried 2 filter configurations: 1st) check if email in the input DE is not null. I changed because it could be problematic while trying to filter data that was not writed yet. [The log was about this 1st option] 2nd) check if Contact.Key is not null. The problem persist with the same error message.

Comment: When you click on an interaction to view it, in the upper left corner of the screen there is a field called "Contact Entry."  Is yours set to single or multiple?

Comment: Can you tell exactly how you created your trigger?  Can you provide a screen shot of the trigger wizard step 3?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this issue when Journey Builder is unable to bind the ContactKey in your Events request to a Contact Record.

I think you have probably missed a step when creating an Event in Contact Builder. Please can you try following these steps.

---

1. The first step is to retrieve the Event Definition Key (a unique identifier for an Interaction Trigger) that you will use to fire the Event. Open Journey Builder from the Marketing Automation menu, then select **Triggers** from the Administration menu.

2. Select the Trigger that you created in the Interaction Canvas and copy the Event Definition Key value.

[image: Trigger Administration] *Retrieving the Event Definition Key for a Trigger in Journey Builder*

3. Now you can create an Event. Events are created in Data Designer within the Contact Builder app. Open **Contact Builder** from the Data & Analytics menu, then from the dropdown menu on the **Create Attribute Group** button, select **Create New Event**.

4. In the Create New Event dialog, add a unique name in the Name field, paste the Event Definition Key value from the Interaction Trigger in the Event Key field and then select the Attribute Group you created earlier. This creates a cardinal relationship between the Event and Event Destination.

[image: Create New Event] *Creating a new Event in Contact Builder*

5. Click **Create** and the Event will be displayed. Now you can create a new Data Extension to contain the serialized Event Data. Click on the **Create New Data Extension** button. This is the preferred method (rather than linking to an existing Data Extension), as Data Extensions that are linked to Events needs to contain additional fields and these are automatically added to a Data Extension when a new Data Extension is created from the Events interface.

6. In the Create New Data Extension dialog, assign a name to the Data Extension. You can optionally complete the additional fields in this step and change the location of the Data Extension.

[image: Create New Data Extension] *Creating a new Data Extension for an Event in Contact Builder*

7. Click **Next** twice and add an Attribute (or Attributes) to store the member preference data. You will note that three required Attributes have automatically been added to the Data Extension.

[image: Adding Attributes to an Event Data Extension] *Creating Attributes for an Event in Contact Builder*

8. Click **Next** and create the relationship between the Contact record and the new Data Extension. In this instance, link the two **Contact Key** system generated Attributes.

[image: Creating Event Relationships] *Creating relationships for an Event in Contact Builder*

9. Click **Create** and click **OK** in the confirmation dialog. You will now see the relationship between the Contact Record and the linked Data Extension where the Event data will be serialized.

[image: Event Data Relationships] *Data relationship for an Event in Contact Builder*

10. Start the Event by selecting the **Start Event** button in the top right corner of the interface. Click **Start** in the confirmation dialog.